# PDFsharp trim page white-space, merge pages

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp

I am merging some PDF documents using PDFsharp, and I want to do the following:
-> the LAST page of FIRST document contains just 2-3 lines of text, so I would like the FIRST page of SECOND document to begin immediately after those 2-3 lines...

Now it goes to the new page, so there is lot of Space-wasting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PDFsharp does not render PDF pages, PDFsharp does not parse PDF pages.

When using PDFsharp there is no easy way to achieve what you want and you will have to add a lot of code to get it done.

It might be easier with another library, but I cannot give you any names.